# (Screenshots) What fonts are those?

Tags: fonts, typefaces

I have been using this Android program - no longer in the Google store (implying: support discontinued) - and I have noticed it uses (what looks to me like) two distinct types of fonts, respectively, for the *edit* view and for the *saved* view. (There are no direct font settings, beyond the size and the color.)

Do you recognize these fonts? I want their names. (Screenshots attached.)

Please and thank you,

[image: The edit view.]

[image: The saved view.]

Answer (score 1):

Those are both Roboto, the standard UI font for Android, but it's switched to lighter weights to represent both regular and bold in the second photo. It could be because the edit window and the display window use different APIs or coding or something, or perhaps the drop down to a light weight represents that it's only viewable and not editable.